# workdir issue in dockerfile

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a flask project as a container, which has error logging and exception handling, but when I use workdir scraper in my Dockerfile. I'm not sure why /scraper gets appended to start of my logger filepapth.

Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.7.9
ADD . /scraper
WORKDIR /scraper
RUN pip install Flask
RUN pip install Flask-RESTful
```

error from console:

```
app_1  |     handlers = _install_handlers(cp, formatters)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/config.py", line 145, in _install_handlers
app_1  |     h = klass(*args, **kwargs)
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1087, in __init__
app_1  |     StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1116, in _open
app_1  |     return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding)
app_1  | FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/scraper/C:/Users/91852/Desktop/scraper/aur/logs/error.log'
app_1 exited with code 1
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    command: python -m launcher
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/scraper
```

Comment: You can't access the host system from inside the Docker container. Make the log file location configurable and use a relative path, e.g. via env variables.

Comment: For Windows, you should define absolute path, instead of relative. I think you should Change `ADD . ...` to `ADD C:/Users/91852/Desktop/scraper/ /scraper/`. Try this

Comment: hey Jan!! do you mean something like this in launcher.py

current_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(current_dir)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(current_dir, 'scraper'))

Comment: ok @saeed, let me try and get back to you

Comment: @saeed do I need to update workdir as well?, because I see error : failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error from sender: CreateFile C:\Users\91852\Desktop\scraper\C:: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: I'm sorry, the path I provided is not correct. You should either do `ADD \\C:/Users/91852/Desktop/scraper/ /scraper/` or `ADD C:\Users\91852\Desktop\scraper\ /scraper/`

Comment: hey! I tried ADD . /scraper and it works fine, since I'm able to get the error from coding side it means everything is being copied to image from my local.

Comment: I said change `ADD` command because you were getting `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error. Now are your problems solved?

Comment: by the way these 2 also didn't help!, if I go with 1st one I get load context error, and 2nd one says "ADD C:Users91852Desktopscraper /scraper/" error, somehow slash got removed during image conversion

Comment: file not found error was,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/scraper/scraper/aur/logs/error.log

if you see it has 2 time /scraper, I'm not sure how come 1st one is coming by default, it is required only for 1 time in the path

Comment: I see the path `/scraper/C:/Users/91852/Desktop/scraper/aur/logs/error.log` in your question.

Comment: hey @saeed thanks for helping and breaking your head for my problem, I was able to solve it by updating logger.conf args section, I took out host path and used /scraper/aur..., and I see project is up, I'll ping if still am hitting a blocker. Thank you for the help and suggestions.